# Per developer launchSettings.json in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

Is there any way of having this file per developer? e.g. launchSettings.machinename.json

I initially thought it should be ignored in git but then I stumbled across this

https://github.com/github/gitignore/pull/2705

I can make a custom profile of type Project but then that's not using IIS. Variations of making a profile and trying to override the applicationUrl haven't worked

Answer (score 2):

I can't see anyway of doing this, however git provides ways of ignoring the changes specifically for cases like this

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/ignore-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=visual-studio

https://medium.com/@igloude/git-skip-worktree-and-how-i-used-to-hate-config-files-e84a44a8c859

To do this

git update-index --skip-worktree launchSettings.json

To undo this

```
git update-index --no-skip-worktree launchSettings.json
```

To view files altered by this

```
git ls -files -v
```